# Is there a nicer UI for karma-runner?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm using [Karma - Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html) for unit testing in my project, the output is pretty ugly, a bunch of lines inside the command line.

Is there a nicer HTML UI for this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use my HTML reporter plugin:

https://github.com/matthias-schuetz/karma-htmlfile-reporter

Just install via "npm install karma-htmlfile-reporter -g" and add some lines to your config.

```
reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

htmlReporter: {
  outputFile: 'tests/units.html'
}
```

The HTML reporter will generate a HTML file you can view in your browser.

Comment: your GitHub page has a line of `plugins:['karma-htmlfile-reporter']`. This line broke the code with a `No provider for "framework:jasmine"`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) has support for running karma tests.  They also show test coverage with a simple plugin addition.  Setup instructions can be found [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/10/running-javascript-tests-with-karma-in-webstorm-7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify an output file in your config like this:

```
junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'reports/test-results.xml'
};
```

The output file is then in the XML format.

Comment: i would be nice that when someone thinks that my answer was wrong or not helpful, to leave a comment before downvoting.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (adding it to the Karma config object). Can you maybe possibly extend the answer?

Comment: For the junitReporter to work you need to install it first. Then add it to the list of karma plugins. then add it to the list of reporters. And finally add its configuration. https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter

Comment: Your response was downvoted because the OP is asking for some sort of nice UI for the tests output. There's no way the XML file the junit reporter generates can be considered as nice UI. I didn't downvote it though.